# How to set paths for multi-page-applications when using vue?

Tags: vue.js

I want to build a web-application using `Vue` which should have a website structure like this:

```
index-page
  |--page1
  |--page2
  |--page3
  ...
```

That is, I have 1 index-page that will be my home-page which contains the link for all other pages.

But, each page is from some category and a sub-category, so I want that the address for each page should be like this:

```
localhost:8080/category/sub-category/page
example: localhost:8080/algorithms/sorting/bubble
```

In my project structure, these categories and sub-categories are placed like this:

```
my-project/src/category/sub-category/page/files
```

```
my-project
  |--src
     |--App.vue    // for index page
     |--main.js    // for index page
     |--algorithms
     |  |--sorting
     |  |  |--bubble
     |  |  |  |--bubble.html
     |  |  |  |--App.vue
     |  |  |  |--main.js
     |  |  |  
     |  |  |--selection
     |  |  |  |--selection.html
     |  |  |  |--App.vue
     |  |  |  |--main.js
     |  |  ...
     |  ...
     ...
```

These categories and sub-categories are placed on index page like this:

```
<h2>category</h2>
  <h3>sub-category</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">page</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
  ...
...
```

I want that any address of the form

```
localhost:8080/category
or
localhost:8080/category/sub-category
```

should lead to index page and addresses of the form

```
localhost:8080/category/sub-category/page
```

should load the corresponding page.

So, how should I configure my `vue.config.js` file?
Can I do it only once for all pages like given [here](https://github.com/Plortinus/vue-multiple-pages/blob/master/vue.config.js) for my project structure?
I only want that my website is working correctly and is developed in the correct way (without using any hacks).
Every page is independent of each other. But each page on its own should be a SPA.

Also, I want to know how these all things are related to each other in `vue.config.js`:

- the string that we put in `href` of `<a href=""></a>`
- the path displayed in browser window
- the path from where the page is loaded from the project

I am asking above question because I have doubt whether the path user sees is same as the path in the project?

Well, since I am using no directory named `pages`, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nuxt.js` was what I needed. The `pages` directory handles it all.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Personally I was building a Vue app with laravel and what I used and mostly a lot of people use is a Vue router.

https://router.vuejs.org/

You can define the links there and it stops the page from reloading and supports transitions for pages. And uses a specific Vue Router href. Hope this somewhat answers your question.